# creat a dictionary from list of 3D tensor and a list

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a list of 3D tensors values called x_train I want to create a dictionary by using them as key for another list.

```
x_train=np.array(pair_code).reshape(-1, 1, 23, 4) 


mat_gen={}    
for x in range(len(x_train)):
    mat_gen[x_train[x]]=gene_seq[x]
```

`

but I get

--> 143     `mat_gen[x_train[x][0]]=gene_seq[x]`
144
145

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: `x_train` isn't.a list of 3d tensors, it is a `numpy.ndarray` with 4 dimensions. In any case, `numpy.ndarray` objects are not hashable, they cannot be keys in a dict

Comment: and as the `TypeError` is saying, the type of your keys must be hashable, which arrays are not.

Comment: thank you for your comment, Is there anything I can do to go around this?

Answer (score 1):

In Python hashables should be immutable. That means you can use int, string, float, tuples as key of dictionaries. But you cannot use arrays, numpy arrays, lists, ... as key element of a dictionary

Comment: thank you for your comment, Is there anything I can do to go around this?